# Visual studio 2015 copyLocal doesnt work for old projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, devexpress

When i create a NEW project, everyting works fine using copy local. It copies all files to output directory or skip them.
The problem is when i use projects that i already created before (in visual studio 2013), when i try to setup copy local = false (for a devexpress dll) it doesnt work, all devexpress dlls are copied to the output directory all the time.

I have read something about GAC and a DoNotCopyLocalIfInGac property from here [VS 2015 copies to output GAC references of a project reference regardless of copy local setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647713/vs-2015-copies-to-output-gac-references-of-a-project-reference-regardless-of-cop), but i dont understand it, besides it's weird that it works fine when using new projects, there must be simple solution for this now with VS2015 update3, but i couldnt find one.

PD: I have being looking for a solution for this problem since microsoft released visual studio 2015, now with update 3 i couldn't find one, besides english isn't my main language and i dont know the right keywords to formule the right question. Any help would be really apreciated.